# How to execute a command on the server with Capistrano?

Tags: ssh, deployment, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a very simple task called update_feeds:

```
desc "Update feeds"
task :update_feeds do
  run "cd #{release_path}"
  run "script/console production"
  run "FeedEntry.update_all"
end
```

Whenever I try to run this task, I get the following message:

```
[out :: mysite.com] sh: script/console: No such file or directory
```

I figured it's because I am not in the right directory, but trying

```
run "cd ~/user/mysite.com/current"
```

instead of

```
run "cd #{release_path}"
```

Also fails. Running the exact same commands manually (through ssh) works perfectly.
Why can't capistrano properly `cd` (change directory) into the site directory to run the command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `run` command basically executes within its own shell environment.  So you would need to do something like:

```
run "cd #{release_path} && script/console production"
```

However, you cannot run commands *in* `script/console` this way as `script/console` is for *interactive* usage.

What you want is `script/runner` like so:

```
run "cd #{release_path} && script/runner -e production 'FeedEntry.update_all'"
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You should use:

```
execute "cd #{release_path} && script/console production"
```

With capistrano 3.x

Comment: What's the difference between `execute` and `run`?  Is it just that the name's changed?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is using within like that:

```
within variable_with_the_folder_path do
    execute :command, parameter
end
```

for example:

```
    # Bower Cache Clean:
    bower_path = fetch(:bower_path)
    within bower_path do
      execute :node, "#{bower_path_to_bin}", 'cache clean'
    end
```

Comment: How can I take the output of an execute command in a variable ?